# Prove that $k$ successive calls to binary tree successor take $O(k + h) $ time

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computational-complexity, trees

This question has been around for while, but I still have a question please. I will discuss the following solution.

Given tree successor algorithm below, that given an $x$, it will find it's left-most node of right-subtree of $x$.

```
successor = getSuccessor (rightNode(x))
Fun getSuccessor(Node node: node of a tree):
 if (leftNode(x) != null) then return getSuccessor(leftNode(x))
 return node
```

**Edit**: I found out that the following is the one used to find successor not the above algorithm
[image]

**Assumptions**: Assuming that the worst-case running time of getSuccessor() is $O(h)$, where $h$ is the height of binary search tree and the tree will not be changed between successive calls of the method. The worst case happens when next successor is a leaf at depth $h$.

You need to call once the method to get the next successor and you need $O(h)$ time for that.  Once when you have the next successor you simply can store it and for every other call, you can return it in $O(1)$. Since, you have $k-1$ remaining calls, the running time is $O(k)$. Combining with the above, you have that the total running time is $O(h) + O(k) = O(k + h)$.

**Question**: I am not sure by the last statement about how we got running time $O(k)$ please? I assume $k$ successive calls to $getSuccessor()$ means that we are calling it $k$ times on probably same or different nodes? If that is the case, we know that worst time for $getSuccessor$ is $O(h)$, so how we got a total time of $O(h+k)$ please?

**Edit**: I would assume probably that $k$ succissive calls to $getSuccessor()$ means: $getSuccessor() + \dots + getSuccessor():~k~times$?

Comment: What is the reference for the new algorithm? Where did you get it?

Comment: @ShyPerson. Sorry for late response. I don't remember, but I will look it up again and update if I got it.

Comment: @ShyPerson It is problem 12.2-8 from CLRS, third edition.